# python : unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

I am using nested for loops to check if the substring **"f"** is present in one of the permutation of given string as parameter in the following function.

```
   import itertools

   def permute(f,string):
        permutation_list = []
        permutations = itertools.permutations(string)
        for item in permutations:
           permutation_list.append(''.join(item))
           for item in permutation_list:                  
               if f in item:                         # unindentation error
                   print "YES"
                   break
               else:
                   print "NO"
                   break  



   if __name__ == "__main__":
   t1=input()
   for i in range(0,t1):
        a=raw_input()
        b=raw_input()
        c=a+b
        print c
        t2=input()
        f=""
        for j in range(0,t2):
           d=raw_input()
           f=f+d
        permute(f,c)
```

It is giving unindentation error at line 10

Comment: Make sure you didn't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: try `python -tt filename.py` to run your code.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary   It is still giving same error

Comment: Check line `permutation_list.append(''.join(item))` for tabs.

Comment: The code you have in your question does not give that error. You have a couple things wrong, though, that still prevent the code from working. For example, all the code starts with indentation; the first level of indentation should be at the left margin. Also, the code under your `if __name__...` statement is indented improperly. When I fix those, your code works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities:

1. You have all other indents at 3 spaces, but your highlighted line is indented 4 spaces.
2. You have mixed tabs and spaces.
3. You didn't start at the first column.

A good Python-aware text editor should highlight these for you and offer a quick fix.

Here is a fixed version:

```
import itertools

def permute(f,string):
    permutation_list = []
    permutations = itertools.permutations(string)
    for item in permutations:
        permutation_list.append(''.join(item))
        for item in permutation_list:                  
            if f in item:                         # unindentation error
                print "YES"
                break
            else:
                print "NO"
                break  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1=input()
    for i in range(0,t1):
        a=raw_input()
        b=raw_input()
        c=a+b
        print c
        t2=input()
        f=""
        for j in range(0,t2):
            d=raw_input()
            f=f+d
        permute(f,c)
```